Why is China's Tiangong space station inaccessible from Russia's launch sites?
I was reading Ars Technica's 9/21/2024 "NASA has a fine plan for deorbiting the ISS—unless Russia gets in the way". The article states:

Russian and Chinese leaders have fostered closer ties in space in recent years, but China's Tiangong space station is inaccessible from Russia's launch sites.

Is the rocket fuel required to reach the Tiangong space station when launched from a Russia site more than the rocket has the problem or is it something else?

Minor correction: the current Chinese space station is actually just called China Space Station, CSS, not Tiangong. Tiangong are the first a few single module space labs, like Skylab but smaller. Tiangong is also the base design of the Tianzhou cargo ship.

@user3528438  ".. just called China Space Station, CSS.." by whom exactly? The answer to my earlier question What is or are the official English names for the eventual space station being built by China, and of the first module that's in orbit now? says "Tiangong ('Heavenly Palace')" and cites the Chinese National Space Administration. Please feel free to leave another answer there and make sure to support your assertion with sources of your own.  See also Wikipedia's Tiangong space station

@user3528438 you can also leave an answer on my related question in meta Is CSS a better tag for the Chinese Space Station Tiangong ("Heavenly Palace")? It turns out that my answer suggesting we use the "css" tag for parity with the "iss" tag was heavily downvoted.

最终决定沿用“天宫”作为载人空间站的整体名称，但后面不再加序号。(In the end, it was decided to use "Tiangong" as the overall name of the manned space station, but no serial number was added after it.) https://www.cmse.gov.cn/art/2013/11/5/art_19_510.html seems they decided in 2013, though 中国载人空间站各 (China's manned space station) is used interchangeably.

You can ask google, thats what i did, lol ;P

@uhoh I couldn't find a direct source but right now all the mission badges use CSS naming https://www.cmse.gov.cn/xwzx/202311/t20231118_54639.html

The Chinese space station has an orbital inclination of about 42 degrees. No Russian launch site can launch a vehicle directly into that low of an inclination. Inclination plane changes after liftoff are possible, but expensive in terms of propellant usage. See Penalty for Neutron dog-legging from Wallops to synchronous? for an example.

Baikonur: inclinations from 50 degrees to 99 degrees
Plesetsk: inclinations are generally 62.8, 67.1, 73-74 and 82-83 degrees
Kapustin Yar: inclinations of 48-49 degrees (this launch site may be inactive for orbital launches - last one was in 2008)

Source: http://www.satobs.org/faq/Chapter-09.txt
Inclination limits are usually based on safety and/or political considerations. See Why is 51.8° inclination standard for Soyuz? for an example.

@uhoh good point. revising.

Geography is important. You have to dog-leg to go to an inclination less than the latitude of the launch site.

China actually have this exactly same problem. If the station had been launched into a 19 degree orbit from the Wenchang, it would not be reachable by the crew ship from the Jiuquan.

Baikonur's latitude is very slightly below 46 degrees, with the 51.8-degree minimum imposed to avoid dropping spent stages on China.  If China wants to be buddy-buddy with Russia, there's no reason they couldn't let the Russians launch directly east from Baikonur over western China (after all, they don't seem to mind dropping their own spent stages onto random Chinese villages), which already eliminates more than half of the plane change that'd otherwise be required (and the remainder could probably be taken care of with a dogleg maneuver during launch).
